# how to set name of file being uploaded in connect-multiparty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have have one page where I want to accept one file and 3-4 user inputs , I was able to achieve this using `connect-multiparty middle-ware` but the name of uploaded file is something gibberish with correct extension and uploaded files contents are too correct.

I want to achieve below things

> 1. Set name of file being uploaded
> 2. Create copy of file with different name if the file with same name exists in target directory
> 3. Set max limit on size and restrict type of file.

I searched on net but could not find any working example. My complete code is as below

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartyMiddleware = multiparty({
    uploadDir : '../public/uploads'
});

router.post('/api/user/uploads', multipartyMiddleware, function(req, res) {

    var file = req.files.file;
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log(file.type);
    console.log(file);
    console.log(req.body.test);

    console.log("The file was saved!");
    res.json({
        success : 1
    });
    return;

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Did you able to rename the uploaded file??? if so please let me know. I'm also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rename the file after being copied using `fs.rename()`, or modify the source code of multiparty inside node_modules. Inside their code they have a function that does the renaming:

```
function uploadPath(baseDir, filename) {
  var ext = path.extname(filename).replace(FILE_EXT_RE, '$1');
  var name = randoString(18) + ext;
  return path.join(baseDir, name);
}
```

I have done some modifications to their code so I could use it a little bit like multer:

https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/999c80df952458cc583272a5161b4d08

You would use it like so:

```
var EXT_RE = /(\.[_\-a-zA-Z0-9]{0,16}).*/g;
var options = {
    uploadDir : path.join(__dirname,'../public/images'),
    filename: function(filename, callback){
     var name = filename.replace(EXT_RE, "");
     callback(name+'-YEAH.png');
   }
}
var form = new multiparty.Form(options);
```

They strongly advise you to save the files in the temp folder to prevent DoS on your server.

https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

You can access it easily, I used this to get file name.

```
 console.log(req.files.uploads.path.split('\\')[1]);
```

I am using uploads from Angular.